# HTML Output from XML and strange characters

Tags: php

Im using CURL to fetch Twitter RSS, then write those tweets to Wordpress.

Here is an example of the XML:

```
  <title>Bob: Twitter&#8217;s @Anywhere Platform Is Now Live - http://bit.ly/b54cTS</title>
```

I then write this to Wordpress, but the result is:

```
Bob: Twitterâs @Anywhere Platform Is Now Live - <a href="http://bit.ly/b54cTS" target="_blank">http://bit.ly/b54cTS</a>
```

Not the `âs` character, can any suggest what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Adding this should fix it. Maybe not the title tag though. I'm not sure about that actually.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere between the data coming out of the XML parser and the page being sent to the client, there is a disagreement about what the character encoding is.

Make sure you use the same encoding (UTF-8 is wise) throughout. (The XML document is plain ASCII so it isn't a problem with the data there).

The W3C provides [an introduction with links to further resources](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-what-is-encoding).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the problem is in XML encoding?